# linux arithmetic expression

Tags: bash, awk

With a text file containing

> aa bb,bb dd,cc dd,dd dd,0,5

and i execute

```
 y=$(awk -F"," -v pt=$test pe=$test1 '{if($1==pt && $2==pa) print $5}' alpha.txt)
 x=$(awk -F"," -v pt=$test pe=$test1 '{if($1==pt && $2==pa) print $6}' alpha.txt)
 add=$((x + var))
 add1=$((y + var))
```

an error saying

> expr:non integer argument

for $add and only $add1 could work. i echo x and found that it contains the value but when i added "A" to test the output i found that only A is shown.  when i added 1 more field to my text making it into

> aa bb,bb dd,cc dd,dd dd,0,5,6

it works fine for all. so i decided to add 1 more column of field at the last column for my textfile using

```
awk -F"," '{$(NF+1)=++i;}1' OFS ="," alpha.txt
```

but nothing seems to be added. Can anyone point out why or provide me with some better way to achieve what i need? Many Thanks. im suspecting it might be due to $6 being extracted without delimiter behind it. i am trying to increment my 0 to 3 and 5 to 8 using my $var.

Comment: Are the two dollar signs in `$$2=pa` intentional?

Comment: For me, your question is difficult to understand. Consider editing your question to illustrate the problem with 1. inputs (you have that), **2. required output,** 3. code you have tried (you have that) 4. output you're currently getting, and 5 comments on what you have discovered so far. Good luck.

Comment: sorry bout the 2 $$. its a mistake.

Comment: i have edited my question. Sorry for the messy question.

Comment: You have two additional errors in your code: you use '=' instead of '==' to compare '$2' and 'pa', and you are missing the closing parenthesis for the command substitution. Your final call to `awk` also has errors that prevent it from working. Altogether, it makes it very difficult to tell what your intent is, what errors you are getting, and just what code you are using to produce those errors.

Comment: hi. Thanks for pointing out. i was doing my program in a virtual machine. so i had to type out the code in here. i hav edited it already. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (although I cannot say for sure, because you haven't stated or given examples of what the values of `pt`, `pe` and `var` are) but I think the problem you're facing involves quoting the variables passed to `awk`. I've also cleaned your code up a bit to make it look more awkish. The following is of course untested, but it should work for you:

```
y=$(awk -F, -v pt="$test" -v pe="$test1" '$1==pt && $2==pa { print $5 }' alpha.txt)
x=$(awk -F, -v pt="$test" -v pe="$test1" '$1==pt && $2==pa { print $6 }' alpha.txt)
```

What are the results of `echo "$y"` and `echo "$x"`? What is the error message?

Comment: Hi. Thanks steve for ur reply. i added in a delimiter behind my last field and it work for my previous code. so im thinking it could be due to the last field not being extracted as there is no delimiter behind it.

Comment: @user1823986: Adding a trailing delimiter simply adds an extra column to the file. This extra column is of course empty. Recall the definition of a delimiter. Have you tried my suggestion on your original file? Again, what are the values of `pt`, `pe` and `var`?

Comment: Hi steve. When i tried your code i get an error saying no such file or open directory. my pt and pe are values i input to search for the pattern. they are aa bb and bb bb which are the 1st and 2nd field of my textfile. var is the input which i want to increment my 0 and 5 with.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks mate - how'd I miss that?

Comment: @user1823986: Would you mind re-trying the edited code? Cheers.

Comment: Hi steve. i tried the edited code and its the same. if i move my expr algorithm above the variable there is no error but the output was only var. i found the way to bypass this problem which is to add another , delimiter behind the last field.

Comment: @user1823986: You should always avoid work-arounds and quick-fixes. That way, you only need to do things once. I've put forward two questions in my answer above. Exactly what part of the code isn't working for you? Also, make sure `alpha.txt` contains unix style line endings. I.e. run: `dos2unix alpha.txt` first. Alternatively, add `-v RS="\r\n"` to the `awk` command. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Building off @steve's code, try this:

```
y=$(awk -F, -v pt="$test" -v pe="$test1" '{print ($1==pt && $2==pe) ? $5 : 0}' alpha.txt)
x=$(awk -F, -v pt="$test" -v pe="$test1" '{print ($1==pt && $2==pe) ? $6 : 0}' alpha.txt)
add=$((x + var))
add1=$((y + var))
```

as I think your problem is just that x and y are sometimes unset but also you were setting "pe" but testing "pa".

I assume var is set to some integer value earlier in your code.

Comment: Hi Ed Morton. i was testing on pe for my $2. i tried your code and there was a syntax error for my $add. the variable y is alrite but the problem lies with my x. Everytime i extract my field 6 to x, and i echo $x, the value is printed out but when i tried using arithmetic expr i get the error. when i echo "$x""A" only A is printed. pe pt and var are input by me in my program and i echo var and it shows the value i input.

Comment: My arithmetic error is syntax error in expression(error token is "0

Comment: I bet you created your file on Windows and so it's got spurious control-Ms at the end of each line. Try `cat -v alpha.txt` to see them and then run dos2unix to remove them.

Comment: Hi Ed Morton. im using vmware player to run my ubuntu. the bypass i found was adding a , delimiter behind the last field.

Comment: @user1823986 - did you try my suggestion? Adding a , after your last field is almost certainly just separating your 6th field from the spurious control-M I mentioned so it's applying a band-aid instead of just fixing the problem.